# Match string that ends with a given substring, except for certain cases, in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a regex `/(.+)_id$/` in a rails application that matches any string that ends with `_id` . I need it to match any string that ends with `_id` except `associated_id`.  How can I accomplish this?

thx :)

-C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/(.+)(?<!associated)_id$/
```

will use negative lookbehind to make sure that whatever was matched by `(.+)` doesn't end in `associated`.

For languages that don't support lookbehind, you can use this:

```
/\A(?!.*associated_id$)(.+)_id$/
```

This will assert that it's not possible to match a string ending in `associated_id` from the starting position of the string.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in rails, if i plug in "associated_id".match(/(.+)(?<!associated)_id$/) i get 

SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):4: undefined (?...) sequence: /(.+)(?<!associated)_id$/
 from (irb):4

Comment: Oh. Ruby does not support lookbehind, I just found out. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a "regexpert" so i'm sure there's probably a better way of doing this, but i came up with

```
/(.+[^associated_id].+)_id$/
```